# Get location instantly after activate GPS

Tags: android, google-api, gps, location, locationmanager

When I launch my activity, I want to get the location of the user, using his gps.
If the GPS is not on, I display a toast to ask him to turn on his gps to benefit from specific functionality.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 34992, this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 50,SelectCinemaActivity.this );
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



    setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);

    requestLocation();
    locationChecker(mGoogleApiClient, Activity.this);

    ...
}
```

My requestLocation() function

```
    public void requestLocation(){

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        latitudeActuelle = location.getLatitude();
        longitudeActuelle = location.getLongitude();
        try {
            initList();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Location not available");

        try {
            initListWithoutDistance();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and here the locationChecker with the Toast:

```
public void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity) {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    Log.i("SUCCESS", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                    requestLocation();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.

                    Log.i("RES REQUIRED", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(
                                activity, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:

                    Log.i("UNAIVALEBLE", String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    try {
                        initListWithoutDistance();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    Log.i("IL CLIQUE", "OK");
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    Log.i("OK CLICK", String.valueOf(location));
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    Log.i("IL CLIQUE", "CANCEL");
                    try {
                        initListWithoutDistance();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

initList and initListWithoutDistance are 2 function that sort result by distance or name.

When the GPS is active, I got no problem.
When the GPS is off, and I click on "OK" button, I can't instantly get the current location. I tried to get the event onLocationChanged by calling **location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);** , but the result is null. I can't call directly the function onLocationChanged because I got no location object.

After several seconds (sometimes 2, sometimes 20...), the event is launched, and the result is tried.

Is there a way to force this event, and to get the current location instantly after the user click on the "OK" Button?

Comment: am i right if i assume that getting location might take a while? maybe that is the problem in your case... btw I dont see any toast, where exactly is it?

Comment: _I can't call directly the function onLocationChanged..._ And you shouldn't either. That's not how it works. _Is there a way to force this event, and to get the current location instantly after the user click on the "OK" Button?_ No, that's not how it works. You need to wait. You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android) and in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates)..

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to force this event, and to get the current location instantly after the user click on the "OK" Button?

No. GPS itself takes some time to get the initial location fix. This has nothing much to do with Android and everything to do with GPS.